# Error after updating Jquery on jquery.ajax_upload.0.6.js

Tags: jquery, ajax, download

I just want share my experience. I use this template : jquery.ajax_upload.0.6 to build a button to download file in VB.NET application. I update my jquery and I'd errors on jquery.ajax_upload.0.6 template (function depreciate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, line 18

```
if (button.size!= 1 ){
```

Become

```
if (button.length != 1 ){
```

And line 230

```
iframe.load(function () {
```

become
iframe.on('load', function () {